# How to implement string to array hash in perl?

Tags: text-processing, perl, hashsum

I am trying to count occurrence of each word on particular line of input. Given example (what I am trying to achieve):

```
$./foo.pl
asd fgh
asd iop
zxc

asd: 1, 2
fgh: 1
iop: 2
zxc: 3
```

Just a program to record, on which line a word occurred.
This script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
while(<>){
    ++$line_num;
    @words = split $_;
    for my $w(@words){
        push @h{$w}, $line_num;
    }
}
for my $k(keys %h){
    print "$k:\t";
    print "@h{$k}\n";
}
```

gives error:

```
Experimental push on scalar is now forbidden
```

But the `@h{$w}` which  is hash, where key is word(string) and value is array, is not scalar. So why is this error?

Comment: `push @{$h{$w}}` is the sybtax fir this.

Comment: @RakeshSharma but the syntx of `@name_of_ar` is just shorthand of `@{name_of_array}`, so why is `@{$h{$w}}` needed, when the `@h{$w}` is its shorthand and thus should be correct?

Comment: Actually `@h{$w}`  is NOT a hash despite its looks. Rather it's a slice of hash values. Think of it like `($h{$w},...) `. Since in this case the slice has just 1 element it will be a scalar. Remember hash values are scalars. And we all know you can't push into a scalar. That's what the error message is also trying to tell us. We need an array for that. The syntax of Perl is  counterintuitive no doubt, but it helps if you decipher it from the inside out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in [Rakesh Sharma's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/600705/how-to-implement-string-to-array-hash-in-perl#comment1121641_600705), the syntax for accessing an *anonymous array* as an element of a hash is `@{ $h{$w} }`. So for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

while(<>){
    for my $w (split) {
        push @{ $h{$w} }, $.;
    }
}
for my $k (keys %h) {
    print "$k:\t", "@{ $h{$k} }\n";
}
```

See for example

- [Hash of Arrays in Perl](https://perlmaven.com/hash-of-arrays)

Comment: Ok, so what does then mean the expression `@h{$_}` -> I want to gain array from what?

Comment: @milanHrabos tbh I don't know, I'm not very experienced with perl

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Perl but from what I see online, for line 4 of your code don't you have to do
`@words = split(' ', $_);` 
or
`@words = split;`

Maybe try this instead:

```
while (<>){
  ++$line_num;
  for $w (split){              #Changed this
    push @{$h{$w}}, $line_num;  #Changed this
  }
}
```